# Why Black Boxes are not capable of transmitting its Critical Data directly to satellite?

Tags: radio-communications, flight-data-recorder, datasets

Why don't airplane include a satellite technology to upload the critical (Voice/Engine etc) data recorded in FDR to satellite. This would be very useful, in case of missing FDR.

Is there any technology/Equipment existing on this issue?

Note: FDR can just to start transmitting the very latest data first followed by old data in sequence before aircraft gets into crashing mode. Probably we do have some specification/limits to determine the aircraft crashing probabilities. Even if FDR is missing from the crash site we will have some limited data(might not be complete data) which got stored after crash trigger.

Comment: Added a note, yeah referred question is partially covers the subject, edited note would give more details on the intent of question.

Comment: There is no technology problem, this can be done. This is a matter of cost, as satellites are involved, and the transmissions must be frequent. Relying on prediction for less frequent communication would not be satisfactory.

Comment: @mins Answer in the question suggest that ~500GB data uploading into satellite is huge cost/bandwidth. What I'm saying is if we are able to find the crashing point, from that point of time start uploading the data until it;s possible to upload. (New FDR data to old data in sequence)

Comment: *if we are able to find the crashing point, from that point of time start uploading*: Assuming you can predict the accident, which is another question -- I don't believe it is reliable... you need to be able to transmit to the satellite, but this may not be the case. The satellite antenna may not see its target due to the aircraft attitude, or there could be radio interference from the cause of the accident, etc . Data must be uploaded at frequent interval, this has a cost many passengers don't want to pay. With 100.000 flights per day, you need a large satellite data flow.